# Need javascript bookmarklet assistance

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have zero javascript experience but have a task which I believe can be massively sped up through the use of a bookmarklet for Firefox/Chrome. I've been searching for a few hours but without luck for any basic tutorials that would give me the help I need.

In short, I'm looking to create a bookmarklet that will search the site I'm on (i.e. stackoverflow.com) for specific, hard coded text. I repeat these searches often hundreds of times per day and am trying to find a way to speed up the process.

I usually search for a single keyword but sometimes in combination, i.e.:
nonprofit OR foundation OR grantmaker (and sometimes include the filetype:pdf modifier).

If anyone can point me in the right direction oor show me a basic snippet of code for this type of search I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: How would "filetype:pdf" work? You said, you're searching for text... (text doesn't have a file-type). Do you want to search for links that point to PDF files?

Comment: I'm not doing a text search, but rather a google keyword search. I want a list of the pages that contain those keywords, and in many cases, specific pdf documents as well. Ctrl-F is fine for single pages, I'm working with websites with thousands of pages, normally my google search would be: "Keyword1 OR Keyword2 OR keyword3 site:site.com filetype:pdf"

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/05/23/make-your-own-bookmarklets-with-jquery/

Comment: @SpaceBeers that looks like overkill for a JS novice...

Comment: @JKirchartz - True but it's a good intro to bookmarklets.

Comment: @SpaceBeers Very true and will be a good resource for me in future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could look something like this:

```
javascript:var s = 'test'; window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURI(s + ' site:' + location.hostname), 'bookmarklet')
```

Where the `s` variable is your predefined search query. The query could be formed in any manner that Google tolerates, including the `filetype:` keyword. Clicking the bookmarklet would open a new window/tab with a search for the given query, within the site you're browsing.

Comment: That's perfect and I can easily customize the search terms should I need to change them in future or want additional variables. Much appreciated!

Comment: One additional question, and not critical but wondering if there's a reasonably simple fix. Is it possible to have the bookmarklet just search the domain even if I execute it on a subdomain page? for instance, I'm on widgets.website.com, launch the bookmarklet and it currently loads site:widgets.website.com. Is it possible to easily have it search just the domain, i.e. website.com?

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:window.open("http://google.com/?q=site:"+document.domain);` will dump you over to google searching on the current domain...